# How to capture the address link contained on webpage with Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

In order to write a Windows batch-file, I want to capture a specific URL address contained in a web page. 
To be more precise, the URL address sought is targetting the latest Windows Anaconda file, so this address is changing with time and versions. 
Therefore I am looking for a manner to capture automatically this information.
With linux a command to do so can be

```
AnacondaLink=`wget -O - https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ 2>/dev/null | sed -ne 's@.*\(https:\/\/repo\.anaconda\.com\/archive\/Anaconda3-.*-Linux-x86_64\.sh\)\">64-Bit (x86) Installer.*@\1@p'`
```

Does anyone know how to do such equivalent command on Windows ?

I tried to pipe `bitsadmin` with `findstr` but the command bitsadmin do not even start when I do

```
bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ %UserProfile%/Downloads/file.txt
```

Comment: `bitsadmin /transfer "anaconda" /DYNAMIC https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ "%CD%\anaconda.txt"` Try use the `/dynamic` switch directly before the remote address. This works for me.

Comment: Yes, this command solve the first part of the problem. Now I need to use `findstr` or something else to extract the useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full working example but an idea how it could be accomplished.

```
bitsadmin /transfer "anaconda" /DYNAMIC https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ "%CD%\anaconda.txt"
type anaconda.txt | more /P >anaconda-crlf.txt
findstr "^.*https://repo.*x86_64\.exe.*$" anaconda-crlf.txt
```

Line 2 ensures that the line ending is CR+LF so that `findstr` works correctly with `^$` regex.